# R knitr Markdown: How do I output formatting from chunks?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I'm writing a Markdown file that uses a `for` loop to produce a series of charts based on the contents of the data passed to them. I would like for the file to include some text before each chart that includes data based on the place in the for loop, so it can't be created outside the chunk. But when I try to use

```
print(paste("##This chart relates to", var[i]))
```

the output I get looks like

```
[1] "##This chart relates to Foobar"
```

What I want, is for the output text to be formatted as a H2 header. I tried adding the option `results="asis"` to the chunk, but that had no discernible effect. What can I do?

Here's a sample of the relevant code:

````
```{r groupA, results="asis", warning=FALSE}
group<-"A"
tags<-unique(unlist(data$taglist[data$Group==group]))
for (i in 1:length(tags)) {
  print(paste("###Commitments by ", group, " tagged as ",tags[i]))
  commitcloud(data,group,tags[i])
```
````

Comment: are you making html or pdf? I find `cat` can be better than `print`

Comment: I'll need it to work for either.

Comment: Replaced with `cat`. Looks mildly better (no "[1]"), but the ## still don't get formated as a header...

Comment: the rmd file I'm currently working on has `cat("##", x$site.name, "\n")` in a `for` loop with `results = "asis"`

Comment: maybe try `cat("\n\n##Commitments", group)` `\n\n` avoids  interference from previous contents

Answer (score 0):

Use `pander::pandoc.header()`:

```
pandoc.header(paste("Commitments by", group, "tagged as",tags[i]), level = 3)
```

Where `level` indicates the level for the heading.

Per @richard-telford - include a `cat("\n")` if you have problems with previous contents.  Tables seem to be especially troublesome.